# Angular Tour of Heroes, HTTP requests: Argument of type 'Hero' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: angular, typescript

In the angular tutorial [here](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6), I am copying this tidbit of code:

```js
add(name: string): void {
  name = name.trim();
  if (!name) { return; }
  this.heroService.addHero({ name } as Hero)
    .subscribe(hero => {
      this.heroes.push(hero);
    });
}
```

The tutorial also explains that: `When the given name is non-blank, the handler creates a Hero-like object from the name (it's only missing the id) and passes it to the services addHero() method.`

I copied the exact code as far as I am aware, but I am unable to compile due to the error:

`Argument of type 'Hero' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.`

The problem is, I know what it is telling me, but I'm not sure how to get around this. I think I'm trying to cast the string to object of type Hero, but I should not supply an ID here (as the tutorial points out).

Is it safe to not cast it as Hero? How can I proceed in this tutorial?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You always can use `this.heroService.addHero({ name:name,id:0 } as Hero)`. It's looks like diferent typeScript or Angular version (not pretty sure about this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that your `HeroService.addHero` method takes a `string` as a parameter instead of a `Hero`, but a `Hero`'s what you're passing. Solution is to either just pass `name` (without the curly braces or `as Hero`), or rewrite `HeroService.addHero` to accept a `Hero` instead of a string.

Comment: My apologies.     this.heroService.addHero({ name } as Hero) is where the error is happening, but I was trying not to deviate from the tutorial. add isn't being called at this point, it's compiling that I am having trouble with hmm..

Comment: Then the service's `addHero` argument is typed as a `string` and you're passing it something that isn't a `string` - a `Hero`

Comment: Aha, you nailed it with this explanation: HeroService.addHero method takes a string as a parameter instead of a hero.. Thank you.